# How to get the ref of a variable of a class in C#?

Tags: c#, ref

How to get a reference of a variable in a class? I am trying to get a reference of a variable use it elsewhere and need the changes to be reflected in its habitat.

```
 public class PowerComINC
 {
     static int IMALF1_A = 0; //INSTRUCTOR MALF ID FOR MISC FUNCTION
     static int IMALF2_A = 0; //INSTRUCTOR MALF ID FOR MISC FUNCTION
     static int IMFIRE_A = 0; //INSTRUCTOR MALF ID FOR FIRE 

     public static ref int GetAssociatedGlobals(string variableName)
     {
         // return ref of variableName
     }
}

...

ref int val = ref PowerComINC.GetAssociatedGlobals("IMALF1_A");

val++;

Console.Writeln(PowerComINC.IMALF1_A); //Print 1
```

Comment: First off, it should be `ref int val =` there. And I think you can use `return ref IMALF1_A;` in your method.

Comment: `string variableName` allways make me feel strange. Referencing a variable by its name is allmost never needed. You can use a `Dictionary<string, int>` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you do this? [Like so](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns):

```
ref int val = ref PowerComINC.GetAssociatedGlobals("IMALF1_A");
val++;
Console.WriteLine(PowerComINC.IMALF1_A);
```

Note the use of `ref` in both the variable declaration and in prefixing to the assignment. (you can also use `ref var val = ...`, i.e. the type will be implicitly determined, but the `ref` is still required).

Where your method is presumably implemented like such:

```
public class PowerComINC
 {
     internal static int IMALF1_A = 0; //INSTRUCTOR MALF ID FOR MISC FUNCTION
     internal static int IMALF2_A = 0; //INSTRUCTOR MALF ID FOR MISC FUNCTION
     internal static int IMFIRE_A = 0; //INSTRUCTOR MALF ID FOR FIRE 

     public static ref int GetAssociatedGlobals(string variableName)
     {
         switch (variableName)
         {
            case "IMALF1_A":
                return ref IMALF1_A;
            case "IMALF2_A":
                return ref IMALF2_A;
            case "IMFIRE_A":
                return ref IMFIRE_A;
         }
         throw new ArgumentException(nameof(variableName));
     }
}
```

However, as HimBromBeere states, there's little point in approaching this problem in this way. The performance degradation of the `switch` lookup will invariably outweigh any performance benefit of directly mutating a reference variable as small as an int, and now you have no encapsulation of your fields whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of relying on names of variables, you may simply create a `Dictionary<string, int>` that holds those information as pairs of string and `int`. Then you don´t need all this `ref`-stuff at al:

```
public class PowerComINC
{
    public Dictionary<string, int> MyDict = new Dictionary<string, int>() 
    { 
        { "IMALF1_A", 0 }, 
        { "IMALF2_A", 0 }, 
        { "IMFIRE_A", 0 } 
    };
}
```

Now simply reference a value by its key:

```
Console.Writeln(PowerComINC.MyDict("IMALF1_A")); //Print 1
```

As per your comment: you can still use a dicitonary filled by reflection:

```
myDict = typeof(PowerComINC).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x)
```

this gives you a dictiobary containing the variables name and a `FieldInfo`-instance that represents the field and which you can then use to get the actual value:

```
myDict["IMALF1_A"].GetValue(null);
```

You can even change this to a `Dictionary<string, Func<int>>`, so yu can directly get the variables value:

```
myDict = typeof(PowerComINC).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => new Func<int>(() => (int) x.GetValue(null));
```

which you can now invoke using this - admitly strange - syntax:

```
var i = myDict["IMALF1_A"]();
```

Comment: Thank you first of all. The problem here is. PowerComINC is a huge class with around 3000 variables. It has been used as a variable in so many places. So changing this to Dictionary would involve changing the existing write/read methodologies of the numerous variables in numerous places.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using dictionary or switch and use search in object's fields instead using GetField() method of Type object.

And all this ref stuff is quite complicated, I found no way to make ref out of GetField().GetValue() resuld, so i'd rather advice you to just make getter and setter for this.

Since your class is static, you must use typeof keyword

And your variables must not be private to be found with GetField()

```
public static int getval (string varname)
        {
            return (int)typeof(PowerComINC).GetField(varname).GetValue(typeof(int));
        }

public static void setval(string varname, int value)
        {
            typeof(PowerComINC).GetField(varname).SetValue(typeof(int), value);
        }
```

Then in your methods you use

```
int val = getval("IMALF1_A");
val++;
setval("IMALF1_A", val);
```